# TypeScript complains when I define a Sequelize model with an id, but don't provide an id when calling Model.create()

Tags: typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using the class style model declaration:

```
export class Supplier extends Model<InferAttributes<Supplier>, InferCreationAttributes<Supplier>> {
  declare id: number
  declare companyName: string | null
  declare website: string | null
  declare contactName: string | null
  declare contactEmail: string | null
  declare contactPhone: string | null
  declare country: string | null
}

Supplier.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    companyName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    // ...
```

Then, to create a new Supplier row:

```
await Supplier.create({
  companyName: form.companyName,
  website: form.website,
  contactName: form.contactName,
  contactEmail: form.contactEmail,
  contactPhone: form.contactPhone,
  country: form.country,
})
```

And I get `Property 'id' is missing in type` from TypeScript. If I do `declare id?: number` the error goes away, but somehow it doesn't feel right, because the ID is not really optional. What is the correct way to make the TS error go away?

Comment: [They cover this issue in the documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/), don't they? What issues are you running into using the solutions they provide? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I must have missed that in the docs, thank you very much. If you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it for the future generations?

Comment: I don't use Sequelize, it was just the top DuckDuckGo link when I searched ["using sequelize with typescript"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=using+sequelize+with+typescript), so probably not really appropriate for me to post an answer (I might muck up Sequelize details). You could I suppose. :-)